# Javascript: Cannot zoom to mouse pointer with svgmap

Tags: javascript, svg, zooming

I have an svgmap which is basically an image of the globe with some paths that can be clicked.  It runs in the browser via a node JSExpress server but will eventually get hosted after dev is done.

I wrote the function below to allow the user to scroll the wheel and zoom in.  I wanted the zoom to be centered around the mouse pointer when zooming, **but this code zooms to the top left corner of the svgmap regardless of the mouse pointer location when the scroll wheel is moved to zoom in.**  I have attempted to take into account the zoom level and reset the viewbox, and using the mouse coordinates, recalculate what the view should be after the zoom, but it is not working.  Is anything wrong with the way it is being calculated? (i.e. the lines:) Or is it something else?

```
const viewBoxX = (svgRect.width / 2) - ((svgRect.width / (2 * zoom)) + pointerX / zoom);
const viewBoxY = (svgRect.height / 2) - ((svgRect.height / (2 * zoom)) + pointerY / zoom);
```

Thank you in advance.  The function is called every time the user moves the scroll wheel while over the svgmap, and this part works, as i have done console.log the mouse coordinates in testing, so I know the listener is working.  The commented code is below for the whole function, to show what it is meant to do, in my mind at least:

```
function handleMapScroll(event) {
    const svgMap = document.getElementById('svg-map');
    const svgRect = svgMap.getBoundingClientRect();
    const pointerX = event.clientX - svgRect.left;
    const pointerY = event.clientY - svgRect.top;

    // Prevent the default scrolling behavior
    event.preventDefault();

    // Determine the amount of scrolling
    const delta = Math.max(-1, Math.min(1, (event.deltaY || -event.detail))) * -1;

    // Get the current zoom level
    const currentZoom = svgMap.style.zoom ? parseFloat(svgMap.style.zoom) : 1;

    // Calculate the new zoom level
    const newZoom = currentZoom + (delta * 0.1);

    // Limit the zoom level to between 1 and 2
    const zoom = Math.min(2, Math.max(1, newZoom));

    // Calculate the new viewBox coordinates based on the zoom level and pointer position
    const viewBoxX = (svgRect.width / 2) - ((svgRect.width / (2 * zoom)) + pointerX / zoom);
    const viewBoxY = (svgRect.height / 2) - ((svgRect.height / (2 * zoom)) + pointerY / zoom);

    const viewBoxWidth = svgRect.width / zoom;
    const viewBoxHeight = svgRect.height / zoom;
    const viewBox = `${viewBoxX} ${viewBoxY} ${viewBoxWidth} ${viewBoxHeight}`;

    // Set the new zoom level and viewBox
    svgMap.style.zoom = zoom;
    svgMap.setAttribute('viewBox', viewBox);

    // Enable or disable scrolling based on the zoom level
    svgMap.style.overflow = zoom > 1 ? 'scroll' : 'hidden';

    // Disable mouse wheel scrolling when the map is zoomed in
    if (zoom > 1) {
      svgMap.addEventListener('wheel', disableMouseWheelScroll, { passive: false });
    } else {
      svgMap.removeEventListener('wheel', disableMouseWheelScroll);
    }
  }

  function disableMouseWheelScroll(event) {
    // Prevent the default scrolling behavior
    event.preventDefault();
  }
```